# Signal and system convolution

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum, continuous-signals, stft

In the convolution equation $y(n)=x(n)\circledast  h(n)$ if two things are given like $y(n)$ and $x(n)$ then how can find the $h(n)$?

Comment: please kindly tell me about continoues signal

Comment: Answer upvotes and better answer validation are required for this question

Answer (score 2):

This is known as [deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution). A typical approach would be to apply a Fourier transform to both sides
$$
y = x \circledast h \overset{\mathscr{F}}{\Leftrightarrow} Y=XH
$$
and divide both sides by the known $X$ to obtain $H=Y/X$. Then apply an inverse Fourier transform to both sides, yielding $h$.

The linked wikipedia article goes into more detail on variations of this approach.

Comment: wikipedia link can you add any picture about this solution please

Answer (score 0):

While the ⊛ operator suggests some symmetry in the operation, $x$ and $y$ are often variable inputs and outputs, whereas $h$ stands for the impulse responses of a "steady", linear, time-invariant system. Hence, I would could the problem (linear) **system identification**. Since you know $x$ and $y$, it can be called myopic (or informed) deconvolution. In some cases, when $h$ is known to smooth the input, it can be called blur identification.

As explained by [@PeterK](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/35625/15892), the most straightforward method uses a transform that converts a convolution into a product. The Fourier transform is a candidate, and the issue with the vanishing of the denominator can be tackled with solutions of the form $Y/(X+\epsilon)$  or $YX/(X^2+\epsilon)$, potentially depending on the nature of $x$ and $y$ (stochastic, deterministic). There are alternatives, such as in [Short-Time Fourier Analysis Techniques for FIR System Identification and Power Spectrum
Estimation](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/136_short%20time%20spectrum%20analysis.pdf), 1979.

A larger field of research (restoration) resorts to finding approximate estimations $\hat{h}$ for  $h$, using additional hypotheses (FIR, positivity, causality), or taking computational errors, noises or system imperfections into account.

Comment: please send me about discrete

Comment: @sohaibsajid The formulation I used can be discrete. Just think about $X$ as $X[n]$